# Portal attack power in ingress

Tags: ingress

Does anyone have the formula for how much a portal can hit you for, when you attack it?
Does the range of the portal attack increase according to portal level?
What is the maximum a portal can hit you for, if it's level 8 and have both turret and force amp?

Can you get hit by more than one portal if you fire a single xmp?
If so, will you take twice as much damage if the portals are identical?

Answer (score 4):

The [Ingress Portal Attack Simulator](http://ipas.graphracer.com/index.html#8,27,6000;8,38,6000;7,28,5000;8,28,6000;7,36,5000;8,15,6000;8,28,6000;8,24,6000/sc10,0,sr20,sc10/337,225,1082,547,1321,-176,-302) gives a very good indication of the portal's attack strength - the author is currently updating for the new shield and link mitigation.

You can get hit by many portals at once - all the ones your xmp hits. The effects add up - you lose XM incredibly rapidly in a built up area, hence the need for tactics such as attacking from an edge and moving inwards if you are a low level player.

As an L8 it is fun just to go in all guns blazing (but expecting to use up a few Power Cubes) - I'll try and dig out a screenshot I took when I hit 20-something portals in one shot in Manchester city centre

Answer (score 0):

The only  I can give you is the attack range of a portal does increase with portal lvl as does the damage dealt. You can get hit by any portal your xmb hits. So if you hit 6 resonators each belonging to a seperate portal you will be hit by it as long as you are inside that portals range which is determined by its lvl. But assuming you were equal distance from and in range of two identical portals you would take equal damage from both as long as you did not move